# Rails 3.1.2 running very very slow. Seemingly a mysql2 ActiveRecord development mode issue

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

It seems the app is coming to a grinding halt in development mode in Rails 3.1.2. I'm using mysql database and am NOT using asset pipelines. Even the tests are running very very slowly.

It's almost 20 times slower than Rails 3.1.1!

Running in production mode is okay though. I'm using thin as my development server and I've got 8Gb RAM on my MBP. It's not my machine cos my other Rails apps are hunky dory.The only change that seems to be causing it is Rails 3.1.2 upgrade. And downgrading seems to bring the speed back up!

Any clues as to what might be the reason or should we just expect Rails 3.1.3?

Comment: Forget it. https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/3678 . Closing the question. Will wait for core fix. Shouldve first checked on github. :(

Comment: This question is still showing up in the unanswered list. Could you close it, or answer it yourself and accept the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem fixed by updating Rails to the next patch level.